# How to select one or more random elements from a database that add up to specific amount

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In a MVC4 app with Entity Framework installed I have a model that has a `Product` that has a property `amount` (decimal). When a user gives an amount I want to select 1 or more *random* products from the database for that specific amount (and add it to the cart via a method).

```
public ActionResult AddRandomProducts(decimal amount)
{
    var r = new Random();
    var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.Price <= amount).ToList();

    // Get the first random product
    var firstProduct = products.ElementAt(r.Next(1, products.Count));

    var otherProducts = ?????????
    //?? select one more more random products that fill the specific amount (if 
         possible, and if not to closest one that is)
    //??

    var otherProducts = new List<Product>();
    User user = db.Users.Find((int)db.GetCurrentUserId());

    foreach (var p in otherProducts)
    {
        user.AddProductToCart(p, date.Date);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { success = true });

}
```

I have trouble with the part between the question marks. I hope someone can give me an algorithm for selecting one more random `Product`s that add up to the specific amount (and optionally for the nearest one that does if not found).

Comment: Since you already loaded all products from the database (`.ToList()`), a simple while-loop should be enough.

Comment: And @alexn can you explain how? The difficulty I have is that it can be one or more products, and it is not guaranteed that a solution will be found. And is there a way to be more efficient without `ToList()`?

Comment: Putting the `ToList()` into your query loads everything from the database immediately that matches your filtering. The logic to perform the calculation you need will help filter your products. As long as you don't do too much "magic", it should be easily translated to SQL.

Comment: looks like knapsack problem to me (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: @KarelFrajtak I think you are right. :-) I will see if their is an easy algorithm available.